Why do people tend to play the same game when its movie adaptation is released?
Recently, there are so many movie or TV adaptations of video games such as Fallout, The Last of Us, Uncharted, Mortal Kombat, Borderlands and it goes on. The interesting point for me is people tend to play the game that gave life to movie, even he/she played it before and know the ending.
What would be the relationship between this urge or feeling and human psychology? I am at least certain that this cannot be explained with only longing for the game or feeling a bit nostalgic.
*Even the movie reception is bad (i.e Borderlands), Borderlands 3 rocketed up in Steam to 12k+. This observation can also eliminate the condition of "I would definitely play the game if the movie/TV is good".

"I am at least certain that this cannot be explained with only longing for the game or feeling a bit nostalgic" - why are you so certain of this? Seems like a pretty simple explanation.
